# Outlined text get distorted when resized

Tags: adobe-illustrator, resize, transform

i'm trying to have a font letter (in this case "r") half green and half gray.So I Created the outlines from the letter and achieved this :

[image]

When I go resizing (making it smaller) it the letter get distorted though:

[image]

Where is the problem? I have the scale effects and strokes selected in the transform palette.
Thanks

Luca

Comment: How exactly are you resizing it - are you resizing the whole letter proportionally? Can you include screenshots showing the bezier control handles for the points each side of the distortion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uncheck "Align to Pixel Grid" on the Transform Panel.

Comment: What exactly does the "Align to Pixel Grid" do. I have seen this option create a lot of problems for me and not to mention that it is in more than 4 places in AI.

Comment: @Jawad it ensures that strokes and fills fall directly on a pixel. This reduces the amount of anti-aliasing needed and helps create crisper, sharper, images for screen. Align to Pixel Grid is primarily for web and UX projects. It doesn't have a great deal of use for print design.

Comment: Great. Thanks. I wanted to ask this and did not want to pose a new question for it.